# Tomcat - JRE_HOME Environment is not defined properly

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

When I start it. That time I get error JRE_HOME environment is not defined properly. I declared that variable on my user variable of system. Still I am getting this error.

```
C:\Users\shraddha>cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin
```

> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat
>   8.0.27\bin>startup The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

This environment variable is needed to run this program

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.27\bin>
```

Comment: What did you set `JRE_HOME` to?

Comment: I hope this will be help you [here](https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/article.html?id=348)

Comment: I set like this JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_{73}

Comment: Did you try it without the curly braces?

Comment: No I will try that

Comment: Now It's working thanks..

Comment: I added JAVA_HOME ="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102" and JRE_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111". Still it is showing the following error: The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program. What to do?

Answer (score -1):

your apache tomcat version is old and your jdk version is 1.8+.

install jdk 1.7.

set JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65"

and start tomcat.

Comment: I have windows xp and seven. i have installed jdk1.8 on win7 and jdk1.7 on xp. i extracted apache 8.0.9 in my computer. i started apache in xp but i was receiving same error in my win7. after set java_home to my jdk1.7 in win7 apache was started. it didnt have jre_home param.